# Retrieving Local File metadata using Javascript / HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, audio, video, metadata

I am trying to create a media library and will have a component where anyone will be able to upload media `.mp4` files that are stored locally on the client's pc.

I want to have a functionality where the user selects the file and `Video/Audio` metadata is loaded. Is there a way using `Javascript/HTML5` to obtain this metadata like in the screenshot below?

[image: File Properties]

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp These will be the only thing you get from using the HTML5 `<video>` tag.

Comment: Regarding DOM properties, there are no such detailed [attributes in `<video>` elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video). Closest thing might be some sort of [FFmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/) JavaScript API providing the data you want.

Comment: I think it depends on the data inside the file.

Comment: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30072946/how-to-get-duration-of-video-when-i-am-using-filereader-to-read-the-video-file). Might be useful. Not sure if you can get all the information you want though. But you can certainly get duration and dimensions.

Comment: @ChrisGeo Having the same trouble. Want to find the frame rate present in the metadata. Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: @JoãoPereira No unfortunately I gave up on it

Comment: Found a solution, if you are still [interested](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40980314/javascript-read-metadata-of-video-file).

Comment: Yes sure go ahead!