# JavaScript - Read metadata of video file

Tags: javascript, html, video, electron

I've been at this for hours, it's time to ask for a little help.

I need to know the frame rate of a video on load in JavaScript/HTML and I'm trying to avoid VLC plug-in or ffmpeg.

The browser reads the video metadata to check the intended frame rate, so how can I do this as well? I read a lot of online things and didn't find anything useful but I can't believe that this is unfeasible.

I'm looking for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26091836/is-there-a-way-to-read-file-metadata-using-node-js) but for videos. Should be simple, right?

Note: I'm building a desktop app with Electron so file access isn't a problem.

Comment: Would any of the answers here help? Seems a related and/or identical question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28420724/how-to-determine-the-intended-frame-rate-on-an-html-video-element

Comment: Nop, tried them all. Ty for the link though

Comment: See https://webrtchacks.com/mirror-framerate/

Comment: Unfortunately that does not give me the correct frame rate.

Comment: wtf, why the downvote? Sometimes I just don't understand this community. @Downvoter, if this is so trivial can you please come and share your knowledge??

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2602558/11322237

Answer (score 9):

You can create a video element with src attribute pointing to a link or local file/blob

```
let video = document.createElement('video')
video.setAttribute('src', window.URL.createObjectURL(file))
```

Add onloadeddata event listener to the element and in the callback you'll have access to the video metadata.

```
video.onloadeddata = function(event) {
  const {
    videoHeight,
    videoWidth,
    duration
  } = event.srcElement
  console.log(videoHeight)
})
```