# How to get the Video Duration from onChange function after uploading in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onchange, filereader, video-upload

I want to get the video duration from onChange function after uploading in react.js. I have shared my code in stackblitz. Link is here - **[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-735kqb)**

I have mentioned in the code where I need to get the video duration. I need it inside onchange function's **reader.onloadend** portion.
Here's my code given in the following portion:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Hello from './Hello';
import './style.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: 'React',
      get_video: '',
      videoAttribute: []
    };
  }

  chosenVideo(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        /*this.setState({
            file_state: e.target.files[0]
        });*/

        var file = e.target.files[0];
        var file_state = e.target;
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = () => {
            this.setState({
                get_video: reader.result,
                videoAttribute: file_state
            });

      console.log("video duration"); // I want to get the video duration here

            console.log(reader);
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }

  render() {

    var isVideoPreview = '';

    if(this.state.get_video != '') {
      isVideoPreview = (
        <video 
          type="video/swf" 
          src={this.state.get_video} 
          className="get_preview_video_class" 
          controls
        >
            </video>
      );
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <input 
          id="upload_1006_mybataz" 
          type="file" 
          accept="video/*" 
          onChange={this.chosenVideo.bind(this)} 
        /> 
        <div>
          {isVideoPreview}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: Don't use a FileReader, moreover with a video. You will have to load it thrice in memory if you do so, while URL.createObjectURL will allow you to play it while allocating only once the memory.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var media = new Audio(reader.result);
media.onloadedmetadata = function(){
     media.duration; // this would give duration of the video/audio file
};
```

Taken from here: [How to get duration of video when I am using filereader to read the video file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30072946/how-to-get-duration-of-video-when-i-am-using-filereader-to-read-the-video-file)

Comment: Thank you. **console.log(media.duration);** perfect