# Set component state, from unreachable variable

Tags: reactjs, filereader, react-state

How I can get `media.duration` to live in a state environment ?

Right now I don't have access to it, even after trying to change state

```
  handleClick(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(this.state.uploadedFile);
    reader.onload = function() {
      var media = new Audio(reader.result);
      media.onloadedmetadata = function() {
        console.log(media.duration); // <-- THIS WORKS!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
      };
    };
    console.log(media.duration) //<------THIS DOES NOT WORK!!!!!!!!!!
    console.log("The link was clicked.");
    console.log(this.state.duration);
}
```

from: [How to get duration of video when I am using filereader to read the video file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30072946/how-to-get-duration-of-video-when-i-am-using-filereader-to-read-the-video-file)

## _________________________________________

I tried this but it did not work

```
    this.setState({duration:media.duration},()=>{
console.log(this.state.duration)
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you use media variable is out of the scope.
Please try this one.

```
handleClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(this.state.uploadedFile);
    reader.onload = () => {
      var media = new Audio(reader.result);
      media.onloadedmetadata = () => {
        console.log(media.duration); // <-- THIS WORKS!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
        this.setState({duration: media.duration});
      };
    };
}
```

Comment: up for way too long coding today

Comment: `"out of scope"` - how about if `media.duration` is accessed inside `reader.onload()`?

Comment: It is possible but you should be careful because you can read duration data before loading media file.

Comment: so why does `setState()` need to be inside the callback rather than just inside `reader.onload()`? :)

Comment: You have to read duration data after loading file is ended. SO I use setState function inside onloadedmetadata function. If you don't, you will get incorrect value.